# it's not working rerendering when array state change in react [react-slick]

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

[image]

This is my React code. 
I use react-slick library. 
I expect 
 1. when clickedIndex changes
 2. it calls useEffect 
  3. option state change 
 4. rerender this EnlargePhto component 
 5. StyledSlider is affected by changed option.
 6.  combineMood_1 array's initialSlide = clickedIndex 
7. ex) clickedIndex = 8  --> StyledSlider start at 8 image.

BUT,, it continuely starts at array's first image.
how can i solve it?

Comment: Please paste code and dont use images on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because `initialSlide` only defines the default starting slide, and cant be used to control it thereafter.

What you need is a ref to the slider then call `slickGoTo`. You won't need options in state any more.

The API of react-slick is a bit bad by the way -- usually calling methods on a ref is an escape hatch and it'd just be a prop but...this is what they've gone with.

```
const options = {
   // your existing options here.
   // They can now be defined outside the component as they never need to change anymore

}

function EnglargePhoto({combineMood_1, clickedIndex}) {
    const sliderRef = useRef(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (sliderRef.current === null) return // because on initial render it will not be set yet, since the DOM isnt rendered
        sliderRef.current.slickGoTo(clickedIndex)
    }, [clickedIndex])

    // return
    <StyledSlider {...options} ref={sliderRef}>
       // existing contents
    </StyledSlider>
}
```